# Different Results between Sequential and Model in Tensorflow despite same Build up

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, sequential

I am trying to move a sequential neural network from the time series tutorial on the Tensorflow website to a functional API one (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#single-shot_models).

The tutorial code is as follows:

```
multi_dense_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24, 19)))
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :]))
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()))
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features]))

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, mode='min')
multi_dense_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])
history = multi_dense_model.fit(multi_window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, validation_data=multi_window.val, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Where I get the following result:

```
Epoch 1/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2391 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3012 - val_loss: 0.2272 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2895
Epoch 2/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2226 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2850 - val_loss: 0.2283 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2908
Epoch 3/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2192 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2820 - val_loss: 0.2230 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2847
Epoch 4/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2166 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2798 - val_loss: 0.2212 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2836
Epoch 5/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2144 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2780 - val_loss: 0.2189 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2809
Epoch 6/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2131 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2768 - val_loss: 0.2196 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2812
Epoch 7/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.2118 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2759 - val_loss: 0.2193 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2827
437/437 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2193 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2827
```

Now I changed the code to the functional API:

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24, 19))
lamb1  = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :])(input1)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(lamb1)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros(), activation='relu')(dense1)
resha1 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])(dense2)
multi_dense_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=resha1)

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, mode='min')
multi_dense_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])
history = multi_dense_model.fit(multi_window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, validation_data=multi_window.val, callbacks=[early_stopping])

multi_val_performance['Dense'] = multi_dense_model.evaluate(multi_window.val)
multi_performance['Dense'] = multi_dense_model.evaluate(multi_window.test, verbose=0)
multi_window.plot(multi_dense_model)
```

And get this:

```
Epoch 1/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
Epoch 2/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
Epoch 3/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
Epoch 4/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
Epoch 5/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
Epoch 6/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 10s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
Epoch 7/20
1532/1532 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9995 - mean_absolute_error: 0.8084 - val_loss: 0.9425 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.7799
```

Any idea why this might be? I tried a lot of things but cant get it to match. Also model.summary prints pretty much the same for both (Sequential is always ignoring the Input Layer but I think that does not make a difference since you have to specify for Models Input)

This is the complete code I am using in case you want to copy paste

```
import os
import datetime

import IPython
import IPython.display
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 6)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

zip_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    fname='jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    extract=True)
csv_path, _ = os.path.splitext(zip_path)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
# Slice [start:stop:step], starting from index 5 take every 6th record.
df = df[5::6]

date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date Time'), format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
wv = df['wv (m/s)']
bad_wv = wv == -9999.0
wv[bad_wv] = 0.0

max_wv = df['max. wv (m/s)']
bad_max_wv = max_wv == -9999.0
max_wv[bad_max_wv] = 0.0

# The above inplace edits are reflected in the DataFrame.
df['wv (m/s)'].min()

wv = df.pop('wv (m/s)')
max_wv = df.pop('max. wv (m/s)')

# Convert to radians.
wd_rad = df.pop('wd (deg)')*np.pi / 180

# Calculate the wind x and y components.
df['Wx'] = wv*np.cos(wd_rad)
df['Wy'] = wv*np.sin(wd_rad)

# Calculate the max wind x and y components.
df['max Wx'] = max_wv*np.cos(wd_rad)
df['max Wy'] = max_wv*np.sin(wd_rad)

timestamp_s = date_time.map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)

day = 24*60*60
year = (365.2425)*day

df['Day sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
df['Day cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
df['Year sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))
df['Year cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))

column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}

n = len(df)
train_df = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = df[int(n*0.9):]

num_features = df.shape[1]

train_mean = train_df.mean()
train_std = train_df.std()

train_df = (train_df - train_mean) / train_std
val_df = (val_df - train_mean) / train_std
test_df = (test_df - train_mean) / train_std

df_std = (df - train_mean) / train_std
df_std = df_std.melt(var_name='Column', value_name='Normalized')

class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
               train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
               label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
      self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])

def make_dataset(self, data):
  data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
  ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
      data=data,
      targets=None,
      sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
      sequence_stride=1,
      shuffle=True,
      batch_size=32,)

  ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

  return ds

WindowGenerator.make_dataset = make_dataset

@property
def train(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)

@property
def val(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)

@property
def test(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)

@property
def example(self):
  """Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
  result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
  if result is None:
    # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
    result = next(iter(self.train))
    # And cache it for next time
    self._example = result
  return result

WindowGenerator.train = train
WindowGenerator.val = val
WindowGenerator.test = test
WindowGenerator.example = example

def split_window(self, features):
  inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
  if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
        axis=-1)

  # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
  # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
  inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels

WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window


OUT_STEPS = 24
multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24,
                               label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                               shift=OUT_STEPS)

MAX_EPOCHS = 20

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

# multi_dense_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24, 19)))
# multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :]))
# multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
# multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()))
# multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features]))

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24, 19))
lamb1  = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :])(input1)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(lamb1)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features, activation='relu')(dense1)
resha1 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])(dense2)
multi_dense_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=resha1)

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, mode='min')
multi_dense_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()], run_eagerly=True)
history = multi_dense_model.fit(multi_window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, validation_data=multi_window.val, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because you are applying 2 non linearity:

```
#Sequential
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
multi_dense_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()))

#Functional
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(lamb1)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros(), activation='relu')(dense1)
# scroll right ------------------------------->                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And by definition, `Dense` layer with no activation, becomes linear layer... So the two models are not equivalent